# Designing a view in IB with Navigation Bar?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I have designed a view in IB(without UINavigationBar). I am pushing that view programatically, now problem is how do I design my view by keep in mind the position of UINavigationBar, alignment is not proper sometimes, as UINavigationBar is not showing in IB. Is there any way to do it?.

Comment: can you briefly explain what you did and what you want.Is you want to know how to add navigationBar.

Comment: try to design a `UINavigationBar`in the _interface builder_ and add a `UINavigationItem` property (`IBOutlet`) to your `UIViewController`, connect the relevant parts to each other, and in the `-viewWillAppear:` method replace the pointers in old `UINavigationItem` to your _outlet's_ pointers. easy. :D

Comment: @Ravi Sharma I designed a view already, now I want to add a navigation bar programatically, while I doing that position of all other controls I am not able handle properly in IB as navigation bar is not present there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Under "Attribute Inspector", Check "Simulated Metrics" section. Select "Navigation Bar" from "Top Bar" combo.

Comment: Ya that helps me to arrange other controls.